# ASP.NET UI Control as property in interface

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, interface

I have a number of pages which implement the same interface:

```
Public Interface myPage

    Sub doSomething()
    Sub doSomethingToTextBox(ByVal textBox As TextBox)

End Interface
```

The function doSomethingToTextBox takes a textBox item as a parameter and performs some action on it.

I know the textBox is contained on every page which implements my interface, and that it has the same name on each page.

My question is: how can I declare the textBox as an interface property? This will remove the need to pass the textBox as a parameter to doSomethingToTextBox()

I must also add that I'm currently accessing the TextBox using get/set methods defined as part of the interface - I don't want to have to implement these methods for each page as they are exactly the same on each page.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
interface IMyPage
    {
        TextBox myTextBox{get; set;}
    }
```

and in the page you have to make a property to return the protected textbox in the page but i can't see how you will use that ?!

Comment: could you provide the equivalent syntax in VB.NET?